# How to set language file dynamicly in TinyMCE v4

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I try to set my script in a way that it's get the language from the `<html>` attribute. As a basic concept that works fine, the only problem is that I have a customized location where the localization files are located.

How do I have to set the parameter [**`language_url`**](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/localization/#language_url) for `en_US`. I tried a empty string `''` as well as the value `false` with no success. I'm getting the error:

> Failed to load plugin url: https://localhost/js/tinymce/langs/en_US.js

That is because there is no language file for `en_US`.

```js
var lang = $('html').attr('lang');

tinymce.init({ 
    selector: 'textarea',
    language_url: (lang === 'en' ? '' : '/js/tinymce/langs/de.js'),
    language: (lang === 'en' ? 'en_US' : 'de')
});
```

---

Is there no default value for [**`language_url`**](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/localization/#language_url)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two comments on this...

If you are placing the language files in the langs folder within TinyMCE you don't need to use the `language_url` configuration option at all. That is only needed if you want to store the files in a different location.  Your example above seems to imply that you are placing the language files in the `langs` folder in your TinyMCE distribution and if that is the case you just don't need that setting at all.

If you really need that setting (but only sometimes) you can use JavaScript to make that happen...

You start by creating a "default" init object as a JavaScript variable on your page and then reference that later. For example:

```
var default_init = {
  theme: "modern",
  plugins....,
  toolbar....
}
```

...then when you want to invoke a TinyMCE instance you can use that base object to make your init:

```
var lang = $('html').attr('lang');
if (lang !== 'en') {
  default_init.language_url = '/js/tinymce/langs/' + lang + '.js';
}
tinymce.init(default_init);
```

Comment: Thx for your comments, that's what I was looking for! And also with your first comment you're right. Normally I don't need that, but in my case its a `java` environment where the language file isn't registered as `java.faces`. So if I don't set the `language_url` it doesn't find it.